# Sonarqube portfolio

Tags: sonarqube, portfolio

I need to add projects to portfolio in sonarqube 6.7.1

what I did I creaed portfolio and added projects by selecting option manually and scan the code by using mvn sonar:sonar command(goal)

but projects are not displayed where I created portfolio

suggest me how to add projects to portfolio.

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done with Maven.

As described [in the docs](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Configuring+Portfolios+and+Applications#ConfiguringPortfoliosandApplications-Calculation(SonarQube%3C=7.0)), you need to install the [SonarQube Scanner](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner) and execute

```
sonar-scanner views -Dsonar.login=<token>
```

Note that from 7.1 (anticipated but not released at this writing) you'll no longer need to execute this command; all measures will be automatically refreshed when the underlying values are updated.

Comment: @RaghukumarGone if this solved your problem, you should consider Accepting it.